# How to assign a class or ID to a table within a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css, json

I have to use HTML, CSS and JavaScript (so no jQuery).

I have created a table that receives JSON data via API. I have a function to show/hide each of the table rows by clicking a check box. I already included the JavaScript function, but I cannot figure out where to place a class or id, so I can connect the function to each of the table rows. Generally, I would add a class to `<td>` for example, like this: `<td class="example">` but in this case it won't work. The code breaks when I do this.

I did search online for hours, but wasn't able to find an answer. I'm not looking for finished code, but rather a hint/help how to achieve this.

This table is created using:

```css
body {
    background: white;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 3.3em;
}

table, th , td {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 15px; 
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-top: -25em;
}


table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
  
#form {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 5em;
}

#googleMap {
    margin-left: 45em;;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#chkbox_display {
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> 
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
<title>Weather App</title>    
</head>
    
    
<body>
<h1>Weather Forecast</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>    

<h2>Please enter the following information:</h2>    
<form id="form" onsubmit ="return fetchUrl()">
    Enter your City:<br>
    <input id="weather_city" placeholder="Entere here..."><br>
    How to display values: <br>
    <select id="weather_scale">
        <option value="Metric">Metric Units (Celcius/mm)</option>
        <option value="Imperial">Imperial Units (Fahrenheit/inch)</option>
    </select><br>
    Number of days to show weather:<br>
    <select id="weather_numberOfDays">
        <option value="1">Today only</option>
        <option value="2">2 days</option>
        <option value="3">3 days</option>
        <option value="4">4 days</option>
        <option value="5">5 days</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="initialize">Submit</button>
        </form>


<div id="chkbox_display">
<form action="#">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Max. Temp.</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Min. Temp</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Rainfall</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Pressure</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Humidity</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Wind Speed</label>
    </form>  
</div>
    
<script>
    
function initAutocomplete() {

    weather_city = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('weather_city')),
    {types: ['geocode']});
    weather_city.addListener('place_changed');
}
        
    </script>    
    
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDgIpTEmegx81sL3ukhIdYVQrPkufyjEj4&callback=initalize&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>

<script>
    
    var longitude;
    var latitude;
    
function initalize(arr) {    
    var lon = arr.city.coord.lon;
    var lat = arr.city.coord.lat;
    
    var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
    zoom:10,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
    
</script>


<div id="googleMap" style="width:600px;height:480px;"></div>
 

<section>
    <div id="table"> 
<!--
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden">example</td>
        <td class="hidden"></td>
        <td class="hidden"></td>
    </tr>    
-->
    
    </div>
    </section>   
    
<script> 
    
function getJson(request) {
    
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", request, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);  
    }
}
}

function fetchUrl() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var city = form.weather_city.value;
    var value = form.weather_scale.value;
    var days = form.weather_numberOfDays.value;
    
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="+city+"&type=accurate,us&mode=json&appid=a0dd3d46dd5b22c0581030acf10af408&units="+value+"&cnt="+days;
    
    getJson(url);
    return false;
}
    
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    initalize(arr);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.list.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        new Date(arr.list[i].dt * 1000) +
        "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td>" +
        getIcon(arr.list[i].weather[0].icon) +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].weather[0].description +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" +
        "Min. Temperature" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].temp.min +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" +
        "Max. Temperature" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].temp.max +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" +
        "Pressure" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].pressure +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" + 
        "Windspeed" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].speed +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" + 
        "Humidity" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].humidity +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" +   
        "Predicted Rainfall" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].rain +
        "</td><td>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = out;
}
    
function getIcon(s) {
    return("<img src=\"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+s+".png\"/>");
}
    
</script>   
    
<script>
    //function to show and hide pressure, humidity, etc.... doesnt work yet. not connected!
    function showHide() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("chkbox");
        var hiddenInput = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
        
        for(var i = 0; i !=hiddenInput.length; i++) {
            if(checkbox.checked) {
                hiddenInput[i].style.display = "inline";
            } else {
                hiddenInput[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest means of achieving this, given the current approach, is to convert the HTML of the `<td>` opening tags from:

```
"<tr><td>"
```

to:

```
"<tr><td class='example'>"
```

And then use CSS to style the relevant elements, for example:

```
.example {
  color: #f90;
}
```

Or, once you've assigned the string of `innerHTML`, you could simply add this line:

```
// retrieves the collection of <td> elements from within the
// element with the id of 'table', and uses Array.from() to
// convert that collection into an Array.
// Then iterates over the array of elements using
// Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('#table td') ).forEach(function (td) {
  // within the anonymous function the 'td' argument is a reference
  // to the current array-element of the array over which we're
  // iterating.

  // here we use the Element.classList API to add the 'example'
  // class-name to the existing (if any) class-names of the <td>
  // elements:
  td.classList.add('example');
});
```

```css
body {
    background: white;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 3.3em;
}

table, th , td {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 15px; 
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-top: -25em;
}


table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
  
#form {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 5em;
}

#googleMap {
    margin-left: 45em;;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#chkbox_display {
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.example {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> 
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
<title>Weather App</title>    
</head>
    
    
<body>
<h1>Weather Forecast</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>    

<h2>Please enter the following information:</h2>    
<form id="form" onsubmit ="return fetchUrl()">
    Enter your City:<br>
    <input id="weather_city" placeholder="Entere here..."><br>
    How to display values: <br>
    <select id="weather_scale">
        <option value="Metric">Metric Units (Celcius/mm)</option>
        <option value="Imperial">Imperial Units (Fahrenheit/inch)</option>
    </select><br>
    Number of days to show weather:<br>
    <select id="weather_numberOfDays">
        <option value="1">Today only</option>
        <option value="2">2 days</option>
        <option value="3">3 days</option>
        <option value="4">4 days</option>
        <option value="5">5 days</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="initialize">Submit</button>
        </form>


<div id="chkbox_display">
<form action="#">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Max. Temp.</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Min. Temp</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Rainfall</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Pressure</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Humidity</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chkbox"/>
    <label for="chkbox">Wind Speed</label>
    </form>  
</div>
    
<script>
    
function initAutocomplete() {

    weather_city = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('weather_city')),
    {types: ['geocode']});
    weather_city.addListener('place_changed');
}
        
    </script>    
    
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDgIpTEmegx81sL3ukhIdYVQrPkufyjEj4&callback=initalize&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>

<script>
    
    var longitude;
    var latitude;
    
function initalize(arr) {    
    var lon = arr.city.coord.lon;
    var lat = arr.city.coord.lat;
    
    var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
    zoom:10,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
    
</script>


<div id="googleMap" style="width:600px;height:480px;"></div>
 

<section>
    <div id="table"> 
<!--
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden">example</td>
        <td class="hidden"></td>
        <td class="hidden"></td>
    </tr>    
-->
    
    </div>
    </section>   
    
<script> 
    
function getJson(request) {
    
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", request, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);  
    }
}
}

function fetchUrl() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var city = form.weather_city.value;
    var value = form.weather_scale.value;
    var days = form.weather_numberOfDays.value;
    
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="+city+"&type=accurate,us&mode=json&appid=a0dd3d46dd5b22c0581030acf10af408&units="+value+"&cnt="+days;
    
    getJson(url);
    return false;
}
    
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    initalize(arr);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.list.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        new Date(arr.list[i].dt * 1000) +
        "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td>" +
        getIcon(arr.list[i].weather[0].icon) +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].weather[0].description +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" +
        "Min. Temperature" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].temp.min +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" +
        "Max. Temperature" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].temp.max +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" +
        "Pressure" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].pressure +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" + 
        "Windspeed" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].speed +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" + 
        "Humidity" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].humidity +
        "</td><tr>" +
        "</tr><td>" +   
        "Predicted Rainfall" +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.list[i].rain +
        "</td><td>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = out;
  
  Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('#table td') ).forEach(function (td) {
    td.classList.add('example');
  });
}
    
function getIcon(s) {
    return("<img src=\"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+s+".png\"/>");
}
    
</script>   
    
<script>
    //function to show and hide pressure, humidity, etc.... doesnt work yet. not connected!
    function showHide() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("chkbox");
        var hiddenInput = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
        
        for(var i = 0; i !=hiddenInput.length; i++) {
            if(checkbox.checked) {
                hiddenInput[i].style.display = "inline";
            } else {
                hiddenInput[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This does, of course, assume that you're correct that you *need* to append class-names to the elements; with no explanation of the problem you're trying to solve by adding the class-names it's hard to offer better advice.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to this, so I am having a difficult time explaining exactly what I am trying to achieve. However, I am simply trying to show or hide each row of the table when the user checks or un-checks the boxes. For example, if the user wants to hide "rainfall" from the table, they can do so by unchecking the box named "rainfall". I assumed that I have to use a class or id to connect the javascript function.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use 'knockoutjs' for filling in the table by returned Json data. For your purpose it is really suitable. Its absolutely easy to learn. If you interested in this approach you may ask me questions in comments. And i will trying to help you to solve your particular problem.

Reference: [Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the link as well. I will look through it to see if I can accomplish this with knockoutjs.